# Logo and text alignment in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want to have a navigation bar with a logo inside it but as I add the logo the line doesn't look fine!

The problem is when I add the pic its like the picture and the text doesnt stay in the same line! not that the line breaks but the text slides down a little while it shouldn't.

```css
body {
  background-color: #C8F1BA;
  margin: 0px;
}
div#gnb_bg {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
}
a.gnb {
  background-color: #99FF33;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  border-right: 1px solid #448811;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
}
img#gnb_logo {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}
nav#gnb {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #99FF33;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="gnb" role="navigation" aria-label="Global Navigation">
    <div id="gnb_bg">
      <a class="gnb" href="../feedbacks/feedbacks.html">feedbacks</a>
      <img id="gnb_logo" src="../images/logo.gif" />
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: try add `line-height:50px;` to `nav#gnb`. take look here to find out more about line-height: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters we need to sort out your html.

Then look at your css your `<a>` if you're using padding etc you need to make it a block level element.

remove the height 50px from your nav that's not something you want to be giving height to. Instead use your padding of `<a>` to get the desired height it helps with responsive.

But because we want it to sit beside your image use `inline-block`

also do not use CSS to define an  tag's height and width you should use the tags attributes so that rendering happens smoothly.

Also you need to use `alt` on images.

your image also needs the following css rule's:

```
img#gnb_logo {
vertical-align:middle;
margin:0 10px;
}
```

So that it sits the way you want it beside your link.

Also if that is your site's logo it should not be inside `<nav>`

If it's an icon relative to the link then instead of using `<img>` use `background-image`

```css
body {
  background-color: #C8F1BA;
  margin: 0px;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
div#gnb_bg {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
}
a.gnb {
  background-color: #99FF33;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  border-right: 1px solid #448811;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
img#gnb_logo {
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0 10px;
}
nav#gnb {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #99FF33;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav id="gnb" role="navigation" aria-label="Global Navigation">
    <ul id="gnb_bg">
      <li>
        <a class="gnb" href="../feedbacks/feedbacks.html">feedbacks</a>
        <img id="gnb_logo" src="../images/logo.gif" height="30" alt="GNB Logo" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: you are so amazing!thank you soooo very much!my html and css just grew to a higher state reading your answer!thank you so much!
(sry i didnt know i should hold shift as i press enter)
just a few questions!
what is that 0 in margin? you wrote "margin: 0 10px;" what is its difference with "margin:10px"
oh i see my enters make no difference!never mind:)

Comment: @aran `margin` is a shorthand for declaring margins in all directions. `margin: 10px` means there will be a 10 pixel margin on all sides, `margin: 0 10px` means there will be a margin of `0` on the left and right side but a margin of `10px` on the top and bottom. furthermore, `margin: 1px 2px 3px 4px` means a `1px` margin on the bottom, `2px` on the left, `3px` on the top, and `4px` on the right.

Comment: see [the mozilla developer's network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) for more information.

Comment: @aran Glad it helped mate. If you feel it's the right answer give me that tik ;) lol, when you see marhin or padding or inded anything with the ability to apply pixels on axis 0px 0px 0px 0px think of it as a clock so the first is top, right, bottom left. It runs clockwise helps me track it.

Comment: Also Woodrow has the 'margin:0 10px' round the wrong way the first one is your y axis AKA top and bottom and the second is your x axis aka left and right

Comment: @DCdaz yeah! sry it just took long till i could give you your tik!bc i went to a trip and then it flooded and we stuck in the road!!!!:D

Comment: @DCdaz well!:D!now that i gave you your beautiful tik!would you send me an Email so i can ask you just a few more general questions?:D!
aranmhdn@icloud.com

Answer (score 3):

If you add `vertical-align: middle` to both the `a.gnb` and  `img#gnb_logo`, that will probably fix your problem.

Pay attention to the top/bottom padding on your link so that it does overflow the 50px height that you assigned to the parent container.

```css
body {
  background-color: #C8F1BA;
  margin: 0px;
}
div#gnb_bg {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
}
a.gnb {
  background-color: #99FF33;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  border-right: 1px solid #448811;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img#gnb_logo {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
nav#gnb {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #99FF33;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="gnb" role="navigation" aria-label="Global Navigation">
  <div id="gnb_bg">
    <a class="gnb" href="../feedbacks/feedbacks.html">feedbacks</a>
    <img id="gnb_logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

First your `a.gnb` class should have a display-block if you want to render padding on an inline tag like a "a" tag. And your line-height must be of 22px if you want to make it fit in a 50px height container (14px + 14px padding top and bottom + 22px line-height equal 50px)
Second, to make your image alignment just add `vertical-align: middle` to the `img#gnb_logo` rule:

```
body {
    background-color: #C8F1BA;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div#gnb_bg{
    margin:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    border-right:10px solid black;
}
a.gnb{
    background-color: #99FF33;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:26px; 
    border-right:1px solid #448811;
    padding-right:2.5%;
    padding-left:2.5%;
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    margin:0px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
}
img#gnb_logo{
    height:30px;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav#gnb{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #99FF33;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the margin.

```
img#gnb_logo{
height:30px;
margin:0px;
}
```

Check out the live demo.

```css
body {
background-color: #C8F1BA;
margin: 0px;
}

#gnb{
    padding:10px;
}
div#gnb_bg{
margin:0px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
border-right:10px solid black;
}
a.gnb{
background-color: #99FF33;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:26px; 
border-right:1px solid #448811;
padding-right:2.5%;
padding-left:2.5%;
padding-top:14px;
padding-bottom:14px;
margin:0px;
}
img#gnb_logo{
height:30px;
}
nav#gnb{
text-align:center;
background-color: #99FF33;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="gnb" role="navigation" aria-label="Global Navigation">
    <div id="gnb_bg">
    <a class="gnb" href="../feedbacks/feedbacks.html">feedbacks</a>
    <img id="gnb_logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x50"/>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: #C8F1BA;
  margin: 0px;
}

a.gnb {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left: .2%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
img#gnb_logo {
  height: 30px;
vertical-align: middle;
margin:5px 0px;

}
nav#gnb {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #99FF33;
  height: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="gnb" role="navigation" aria-label="Global Navigation">
    <div id="gnb_bg">
      <img id="gnb_logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
      <a class="gnb" href="../feedbacks/feedbacks.html">Website</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```